# Determine character after 4th pipe delimiter occurence in powershell and move file

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with a number of pipe delimited one line text files in it.  I need to find and move files that match a pattern to one folder and move non-matches to a different folder.

Example:

file1.txt contains State|Ohio|Zip|43001|1|Fred|Smith

file2.txt contains State|Kentucky|Zip|40006|3|Henry|Higgins
etc.

Using powershell, I need to find and move all files where the 5th field (occurring after 4th pipe delimiter)is equal to a specific value such as 1.  Then I need to move all of the files where the 5th field does not equal 1 to a different folder.  I can't modify the contents of any text file.

I cannot figure out the combination of Powershell and possibly RegEx to find and move the files.

Thanks.

[edit]
Additional code added...it does find the value in the 5th field as desired, I just haven't quite gotten the move statement completed yet and I know my code isn't most efficient. Added "-Raw" in the Get-Content line due to non-printing carriage returns/line feeds that were embedded in the file.  Seems to have fixed the problem I was having with unrecognized pipe characters.

```
$sourcepath = "D:\Infiles"  
$destpath1 = "D:\Outfiles1"  
$destpath2 = "D:\Outfiles2"  
Set-Location $sourcepath  
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath -Recurse 
foreach ($file in $files)  
{
    $testtext = Get-Content $file -Raw  
    $fields = $testtext.Split('|')  
    $Field5=$fields[4]
    # write the output to test the code
    Write-Output $Field5
    # insert code here to move file to destination path based on the value of $Field5
}
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] of any kind?  Any code yet so far?

Comment: There's no reason to use a regex here - Powershell has a cmdlet which can parse your structured data and give you an object which lets you access it in a much more convenient way. Show us what you've attempted thus far and we'll get you back on track.

Comment: import csv using pipe as delimiter and create custom headers i not already present. Filter on desired column and output to file.

Comment: I've added my existing code to original post.  @Nkosi I'm not looking to output to file, I need to move the existing file based on criteria of value in the 5th field of the text file.

Comment: @alroc code is added

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to preserve the source directory's structure, add this to the end of your loop:

```
if ($Field5 -eq 1) {
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destpath1;
} else {
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destpath2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @alroc.  Exactly what I needed to finish this off.